# Control physical memory location

Tags: c++, winapi

A project I'm working with incurred curious behavior during benchmarking:

- Apparently at random, its runtime roughly halves and, relatively rarely, sometimes decreases by an additional 50%.

  1. To avoid issues with Windows' scheduler we pinned the threads to individual logical cores, to no avail.
  2. Since the software is relatively bandwidth-intensive we suspect that in some cases, allocations are spread between different DIMMs, increasing the available bandwidth; the system in question supports up to four memory channels.
  3. We're currently limited to Windows, so the question would be to achieve this bandwidth increase deterministically.
- So far I haven't come across a function or method to achieve this; perhaps such a thing is possible with the WinAPI?

Comment: That sounds more like a NUMA issue: memory closer to another CPU socket is being used rather than near the current socket. And while there are Win32 APIs that allow some control it would not be at the individual DIMM level but at the CPU socket level. [This seems a decent starting point](https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/windowsthreadsprocessapis7_3.html).

Comment: We would appreciate some more details, code?

Comment: Code and details will be difficult; the project is relatively large. The offending CPU is a Threadripper 2990WX, we did already enable UMA mode in the EFI. The threads are being created and managed via OpenMP and pinned to individual cores via SetThreadAffinity.